# Is it correct to add a trend and dummy variables together to an OLS model?

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, least-squares, trend

I struggle with probably a very simple question. Is it correct to add a trend and dummy variables together to an OLS model?

For instance, J. Wooldridge in Introductory Econometrics adds trend variable to multiple regression, however, I was not able to find a model which includes multiple regressors, and both trend and dummy variables (e. g. seasonal dummies).

Comment: There may not be a single "correct" answer to your model selection problem. What form of incorrectness are you most worried about? Incorrect inferences? Poor predictions? Residual confounding?

Comment: Thank you for commenting on my question. I am worried about model misspecification, and incorrect inference. I do not plan to use fixed effects model in this case. I want to estimate a simple OLS model which will include a trend “t”, a set of 11 seasonal dummy variables (for months), and other independent variables (time series data - macroeconomic variables). I read in “Introductory Econometrics” by J. Wooldridge that I can add trend variable to a multiple regression in order to deal with the spurious regression problem, but I do not know if I can also add seasonal dummies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by dummy variables you mean one dummy for every time period, then it is not correct.

Why? because if you have time dummies (aka time fixed effects), you are already controlling for any possible common time pattern, not just a "trend". More technically, if you add a time trend to a regression with time fixed effects, the time trend would be perfectly collinear with the time fixed effects and you would have to drop it from the regression.

(If your dummies are only Jan, Feb, .. Dec dummies, so Jan2015 and Jan2016 share the same dummy, then it would be correct to include both trends and the dummies)

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer and I saw different opinions somewhere else, I'll repost them here for further discussion. https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1462346-time-dummies-and-time-trend-simultaneously